# right way to validate to inputs using ajax or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, validation

My question is if I can validate two input date where I chose a date, I try doing something like this

```
$(function() {
var Fecha1 = $('#popupDatepicker');
var Fecha2 = $('#popupDatepicker1');
    if (Fecha1  == Fecha2) {
      alert('La fechas no pueden ser la misma.');
    }
});
```

but I suppose it doesn't work, if someone can help me, the idea is when the user chose a date, it can't be same the other date
here is the inputs

```
Congelar desde:<input type="text" id="popupDatepicker2" name="Fecha_inicio_congelacion" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_actualizarCursoCliente['Fecha_inicio_congelacion'], ENT_COMPAT, 'iso-8859-1'); ?>" size="8">
<br />
Hasta el:<input type="text" id="popupDatepicker3" name="Fecha_fin_congelacion" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_actualizarCursoCliente['Fecha_fin_congelacion'], ENT_COMPAT, 'iso-8859-1'); ?>" size="8">
```

I wondering if I can to use the value name="", so I can validate the inputs?

Comment: Do you want to validate whats inside of the text? Since they are input type of text why don't you use `var Fecha1 = $('#popupDatepicker').val();` and compare the values?

Comment: @AKADER yes that I want, but now I had a problem the value by default is 0000-00-00, then when load the page the script show up

Comment: Post all of your code, it is a little hard to understand your problem now. Are you trying to work with the value before page load? Before the DOM loads? that might be  why you are getting 0000-00-00.

Comment: Do not use the [tag:jquery-validate] tag unless the question is specifically about this plugin.  Edited.  Thanks.

Comment: You need provide more code - Firstly, I believe your conditional statement __if (Fecha1  == Fecha2)__ compares one string to another. Secondly, it is not clear if someone has entered the date  as 20160224 or 24022016 or 02242016 or something with separators like 2016/02/24. If you don't know the difference between a number and a string then you need read more. Basically, if A=1 and B=1, and if C=A+B, then C=2. However, if A="1" and B="2" and C=A+B, then C="11". Why? Notice the double quotes? One equation is mathematical, the other is a concatenation.

Comment: @fiprojects I know, but I suing a jquery to chose the date where when the user chose a date from this, the date has this format 2016-02-24, then if I compares **Fecha1 == Fecha2** both has the same format, so isn't necessary validate every value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work... it is untested... Make sure it executes after the dates have been input. Failing that, you need post more of your code like @AKDADER says

```
// Convert data to a string, 
// replace non-numeric input with an empty space
// then convert the result into a numeric variable
var fecha1=Number( $('#popupDatepicker').val().toString().replace(/-|\s|\./g,"").replace(/([^0-9])/g,"") );
var fecha2=Number( $('#popupDatepicker1').val().toString().replace(/-|\s|\./g,"").replace(/([^0-9])/g,"") );

if( fecha1<fecha2 )
{ 
 // fecha1 is older than fecha2
}
else
{
 // fecha1 is equal to or more recent than fecha2
}
```